# Assigning bool? to bool

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, nullable

Consider the following code:

```
bool x;
bool? y = null;
x = y?? true;
```

Assigning a `bool?` to a `bool` is a compile-time error, but the above code succeeds both at compile and run-time. Why? Although the 3rd statement ensures we never assign `null` to `x`, in case `y` is not null, we're still assigning a `bool?` to a `bool`, so it should be an error from compiler's POV, no?

Or is it that C# compiler is smart enough to find out that a particular piece of code cannot possibly create a situation where a `null` would be assigned to `x`?

Comment: Do you know what the `??` operator does? It literally means "If the left hand side is null use the right hand side". If you made the right hand side a `bool?` too it would not work.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Correct, but knowing whether the left-hand side is null or not is only to be determined at runtime. So from compiler's POV, shouldn't this still be an error?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Thanks mate, I just see it now. Can't believe how I missed the point here. For the rest of us, my assertion above is incorrect, so ignore it. I'm keeping it here for history. The point here is that the entire RHS (`y?? true`) is a single expression, which is not going to be of type `bool?` (see Jon's answer for an explanation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of this expression:

```
y ?? true
```

is `bool`, not `bool?`.

From section 7.13 of the C# 5 spec:

> The type of the expression `a ?? b` depends on which implicit conversions are available on the operands. In order of preference, the type of `a ?? b` is A<sub>0</sub>, A, or B, where A is the type of a (provided that a has a type), B is the type of b (provided that b has a type), and A<sub>0</sub> is the underlying type of A if A is a nullable type, or A otherwise. Specifically, `a ?? b` is processed as follows:
>
> - If A exists and is not a nullable type or a reference type, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If `b` is a dynamic expression, the result type is dynamic. At run-time, `a` is first evaluated. If `a` is not null, `a` is converted to dynamic, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated, and this becomes the result.
> - Otherwise, if A exists and is a nullable type and an implicit conversion exists from `b` to A<sub>0</sub>, the result type is A<sub>0</sub>. At run-time, `a` is first evaluated. If `a` is not null, `a` is unwrapped to type A<sub>0</sub>, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated and converted to type A<sub>0</sub>, and this becomes the result.
> - Otherwise, if A exists and an implicit conversion exists from `b` to A, the result type is A. At run-time, `a` is first evaluated. If `a` is not null, `a` becomes the result. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated and converted to type A, and this becomes the result.
> - Otherwise, if `b` has a type B and an implicit conversion exists from a to B, the result type is B. At run-time, `a` is first evaluated. If `a` is not null, `a` is unwrapped to type A<sub>0</sub> (if A exists and is nullable) and converted to type B, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated and becomes the result.
> - Otherwise, `a` and `b` are incompatible, and a compile-time error occurs.

In your case, we're in the third bullet:

- A is `bool?`
- A<sub>0</sub> is `bool`
- B is `bool`

... so the result type is `bool`, and you can assign that to a variable of type `bool`.

Comment: First? `y` is first here, isn't it?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Sorry, wrong way round - although I'm explaining it incorrectly anyway. Editing to quote from the spec.

Comment: No wonder why you're the likeliest person to convert that "k" in your reputation into "m" in 2014! Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
bool x;
bool? y = null;
x = y?? true;
```

`y ?? true` is syntactic sugar for `y.HasValue ? y.GetValueOrDefault() : true`. So you are really assigning a `bool` in the compiler's POV. Take a look at the generated IL to see what's happening behind the C# language's features.

Take a look at [`ILDasm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Playing with it will teach you a lot about the language!

Answer (score 0):

See remark section on this link and you can know why:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173224.aspx

> A nullable type can contain a value, or it can be undefined. The ??
>   operator defines the default value to be returned when a nullable type
>   is assigned to a non-nullable type